# How to pass values from hidden_field_tag through link_to params (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-field, link-to

I would like to click on a link and pass in a value from an existing hidden_field_tag (which is updated on multiple occasions in other events) in a simple_form.

Here is some sample code:

```
= hidden_field_tag :tag_value, "starting_value", id:"tag_id"
...

=link_to "Submit", controller_method_path(value1: @id, value2: **not sure what comes here but should be :tag_value**), remote: true, method: :get
```

I'm not sure what syntax I should be using to get the value of the hidden tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a click event to "submit" and use a mask as value2:

```
=link_to "Submit", controller_method_path(value1: @id, value2: "#####"),onclick: "change_action()", remote: true, method: :get
```

Then, write the javascript function to handle the click event:

```
function change_action() {
    // If your form is unique on the page and it has no id:
    var tag_value = document.getElementById('tag_id').value;
    document.forms[0].action = document.forms[0].action.replace("#####",tag_value);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I thought of using .click but didn't think of replacing the value in the href. My form is not unique so I just added IDs. That way, I couldn't use "#####" because it's represented differently when I using document.getElementById. I just chose some other value and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

A less *obtrusive* way of doing this would be to assign the `tag_value` to the `link_to` helper method, giving it an id in the process:

```
link_to "Submit", controller_method_path(value1: @id, value2: :tag_value), 
                                             remote: true, method: :get, :id => 'example'
```

Then use jQuery `.click()` eventListener to trigger a function that assigns the true value of `tag_value` to `value2:` like so:

```
$('#example').click(function(){
  this.href = this.href + '&value2=' + $('#tag_id').val();
});
```

If your example is similar to something I have worked on, you might notice that passing `tag_value' to the link_to method just passes ':tag_value', rather than the contents of the hash itself- so really, you could put anything here. The magic is the jQuery/ javascript grabbing the value stored in your hidden_tag_field and swapping it with ':tag_value' within the generate link_to html.

The onClick method can be considered bad practice because it's injecting javascript into your generated HTML code, which ideally, should be kept separate.